# CPU does not support KVM, but I want to run android emulator in Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Computer

Tags: android, virtualization, hp, kvm-virtualization

I have set up my react Native environment on an HP UEFI Computer running Ubuntu 18.04.
When I try to run an emulator using AVD, I get the following error:

> Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_10_by_Google' emulator:
>   ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm

I have tried to install kVM as shown online, and when I run

```
sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
```

I get the error

> INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions KVM acceleration can NOT be used

When I run the command

> egrep -c '(vmx|svm)'

I get the output

> 0

My computer is an HP 250 Laptop . Intel Pentium 
Any help or directions on this issue, especially how to get my Emulator running, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you enabled virtualization extensions or support in your BIOS/firmware yet?

Comment: I do not see anything in my Bios that is related to virtualization

Comment: @K7AAY unfortunately, I do not have the edit privileges on this platform. but the results of the command gives 0

Comment: Yes, I do and I just edited the question. I didnt understand your comment the first time

Comment: I do believe that VirtualBox can do virtualization without hardware support.  You might look into that. I am not sure you can run all guest operating systems that way, but Android has a Linux kernel, so it will probably work.
From what I know KVM needs hardware virtualisation.

Comment: @K7AAY I added it , please check the post